# How to access http headers in volltron agent that is configured with enable_web=True

Tags: volttron

In a volttron web enabled agent, I would like to provide custom security based on jwt token.
The token shall be sent with the http header of the request.

I already tried to debug the volttron stack, but didn't find a hint where the header was handled or removed.

I would like to get the header information as part of the environment (env).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header from the call to the web endpoint.  Then you can validate that by passing that to the vip.web.get_user_claims(bearer) subsystem call.

https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/develop/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/web.py#L75

''''

## An example method

def text(self, env, data):
    claims = self.vip.web.get_user_claims(env.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'))

```
Note I don't include the bearer error.

Craig
```